# User didn't like my edit and rolled back, should I edit again?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollback-wars

I recently edited the code formatting of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25608086/1841194). I had only put the code into a code block. But yesterday the author of the post rolled back my edit to the previous version.

I wonder why some people don't like their posts to be edited. Now my question is: Should I edit such posts again?

Comment: I'm OK with that sort of edit; I'd prefer it if it were readable (that is, no horizontal scrollbar), and that you fixed other issues with the post, too.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of answer edits in terms of changing code. Instead comment on what is wrong and let the author decide whether it they want to accept your suggestions. But looking at your edit it is just a formatting edit not actual code changes so I have no problem with this *(sorry should have read the question more carefully)*.

Comment: The only time I get really annoyed is when 'they' edit out an essential (many times subtle) part of an answer I gave. The occasional "Let's add more `code tics`" rages just make me sigh...

Comment: This is usually because such users haven't quite grasped that content posted on StackOverflow, while associated with them, doesn't belong to them the moment they hit "Submit". They think it's still "theirs" rather than "the community's".

Comment: The only thing I worry about is someone might edit it to try to improve it, but might end up incorrectly changing the question to what they _think_ I'm trying to say.

Comment: Some edits change the emphasis of what is the problem. If the emphasis is wrong, then the original author will get frustrated. It is worth reviewing your edit before posting to make sure that the edit is making the issue clearer-rather than changing the question altogether by changing the emphasis.

Comment: @Makoto: There is no scrollbar for me...

Comment: FWIW, I had one of my first questions "improved" (the terminology "corrected") by someone and it really frosted me.  I didn't realize at the time that I could have rolled it back.  While I'm all in favor of fixing code formatting or maybe helping someone who's not a native English speaker with their wording, you need to leave peoples' "expression" alone.

Comment: @TylerH, actually it's still theirs, it's just licensed to Stack Overflow and its users AFAIK.

Comment: These days, there are off-site harassing episodes against folks who edit stuff. Praise the heavens, voting (down) is anonymous.

Comment: @Bruno Nah there's been a lot of language by people that "you don't own it anymore". That means it's not yours more than it means other people can edit it, IMO.

Comment: @TylerH I get what you're saying. I still think people still "own" their contribution (even with a looser notion of ownership) on SO (as explained in my answer below).

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Simply put, people don't like other people touching their things without their permission. You wouldn't want some random guy putting a bunch of gnomes on your lawn if you didn't like gnomes, would you? (Although I would totally dig having *pink flamingos* on my lawn. For free.)

Except that's not the mindset here. It's not about people messing with your stuff without your permission. It's about collaborative editing to improve content quality for everyone.

Generally, if someone rolls back an edit you've made, it's a good idea not to keep pushing their buttons if your edit isn't absolutely necessary. But in this case, the formatting *is* necessary, and to remove it, especially after someone has helpfully edited it in for you, is *inappropriate*. You should probably let the user know how post formatting works here, and, if they stubbornly refuse, flag the answer and let us know. Don't push it any further or you may find yourself in a rollback war.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, so I should edit again ?

Comment: Well, I can do it for you if you prefer, and I'll see if the user reacts again.

Comment: Thanks again, you're really a great moderator here

Comment: No problem, I've done that now. And thanks too :)

Comment: Why not leave a comment asking the original author why they rolled it back?

Comment: @MarkJ Because such discussions are unlikely to remain constructive.  Just let a moderator handle it.

Comment: @MarkJ: Because whatever their reason, they're wrong.

Comment: "You should probably put it back in and let the user know how post formatting works here" Absolutely not, this has been covered pretty thoroughly in other meta discussions.  Once its rolled back one time, don't get into an edit war, as there is nothing productive to come from it.  **Flag for moderator attention and walk away**

Comment: @AaronLS: You're right, I probably do it because *I'm* a moderator and so people seem to listen to me.

Comment: Although I should have put a condition, you should probably ask yourself if your rolled back edit was a necessary edit or preference.  If it is only preference, then don't flag for moderation, and just take it as agreeing to disagree with the OP on preference.  Comment politely with your suggestion describing the intention of your edit, and leave it to the OP to consider your comment and apply the edit themselves.

Comment: @BoltClock True, a moderator would consider the edit and make a final decision and put an end to the edit war.  So yes, what a moderator would do versus how the rest of us should handle the situation is slightly different.

Comment: Warning: unless you include your physical address, this answer may not cause pink flamingos to appear on your lawn.

Answer (score 15):

BoltClock covered the general policies. Editing the post once is perfectly fine. But once the author rolls it back, it's mostly smarter to leave it alone. There are plenty of other posts that could profit from some good editing, and your energy is much better spent helping people who actually appreciate your help, than getting involved in an edit war.

I wanted to add one aspect that I think is important: If your edit had still gone through the review queue, and I had seen it there, I would have rejected it as Too Minor. Not necessarily because it was fairly minor, but because it was incomplete. Once you start editing posts, you should fix **all** obvious problems with the post, not only one aspect. The post under discussion has an obvious spelling error ("devise" instead of "device") that you did not fix.

Well, unless I was in a bad mood, I probably would have used the Improve button in the review queue to fix the typo, and then approved it. But the point about addressing all the problems in a post when you edit them still applies.

Comment: I disagree, if the edit has made a substantial improvement then even if other things could still be improved it's a useful edit. For example a dyslexic editor may well be able to improve code formatting, etc - but not be able to help with spelling errors. It's a collaborative process so all steps in the right direction should be kept (unless they really are trivial).

Comment: No spelling error is obvious to everyone - especially if the editor is not a native speaker. And even when he is, spelling mistakes are easily missed. Let's say that one *should **try** to fix all problems that they spot* :-)

Comment: @TimB: This leads into the whole "what makes an edit too minor" debate, which has provided enough material for many threads. I hope a better solution for the editing (and edit review) system will be found. In any case, I tried to avoid having too much vagueness and exceptions in my answer here. But it's obviously not as black and white. I wouldn't vote to reject a valuable and comprehensive edit just because a couple of minor items were missed.

Comment: @Bergi: I generally agree. This one was hard to miss, though. The original edit was only adding 4 characters of whitespace, and capitalized one letter. When I read the *only* sentence of text in the answer, my immediate reaction was "What does this even mean???". It made no sense at all. Not just a harmless typo, but "devise" is a completely different word from "device".

Comment: @RetoKoradi: why on earth would you reject an obviously useful edit as too minor?  I mean, you explained your reasoning ("it is better to fix all the errors"), but that reasoning is illogical. An improvement is an improvement; rejecting an improvement is to deliberately choose the worse representation.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: That's a complex topic. Search for "Minor Edit" on MSE, or here on MSO, and you will find discussions with enough posts and comments to keep you busy for days. Ironically, I was just invited to a chat session by another user because I'm supposedly approving edits that they think are too minor (which were much more significant than the one in question here). And here I get significant pushback for stating that I would reject certain edits for being too minor. Which illustrates the wider range of opinions on the topic.

Answer (score 9):

To answer you question in general, from my own experience, most edits to my responses have changed the meaning, in a bad way.  Some editors have even put words in my mouth.  Beyond that I also care when when someone makes an arbitrary change (such as removing the 2nd space after a period) that does not add to the value of the answer.

I don't care if someone corrects a typo or formats my code samples better.

Comment: Personally the one that bothers me is "formatting" edits that introduce errors into the code that weren't there before.

Answer (score 5):

In this particular case, I'm not sure I agree that your edit is a good one.

Yes, code should be put in a code block. But the author's original version showed the full answer directly to the reader. Your edit requires horizontal scrolling. I would have been annoyed with such an edit, if it had been an answer I had written.

That said, rolling it back was also not the right thing to do, especially without a comment. Both you and the OP should have edited, and didn't edit, the answer in such a way that the edit clearly was a clear improvement, not something that improves one aspect of the answer and hurts another.

The OP's version, hard to read:

SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
String dateFormat = s.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

Your edit, still a bit unnecessarily hard to read:

```java
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
String dateFormat = s.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

One of the possible approaches to make it easy to read:

```java
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                                          Locale.getDefault());
String dateFormat = s.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

And another:

```java
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(
   "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
   Locale.getDefault()
);

String dateFormat = s.format(new Date(
   System.currentTimeMillis()
));
```

Both of these avoid horizontal scrolling. In the latter, `System.currentTimeMillis` is only on its own line for symmetry with the surrounding code.

Comment: I'd have at least aligned the `=` characters. Feel free to roll this back but I'm going to add my suggestion.

Comment: Oh, rolling back is so tempting... :) I don't think your approach is one that I'd ever use myself. I have no objection to it whatsoever in anyone else's code, and I agree it's easy to read, but there's just something about it, I don't quite know what, that suggests to me that there are better ways to write it.

Comment: You will find lots of disagreement on alignment of `=`. Some languages encourage one style or the other. That said, lining up just *two* instances is almost never worth it. In this case, it makes the second instance look sloppy, as though you accidentally tapped the space bar twice instead of once. I mean, the lines aren't even close to "parallel" in form or in meaning. Really, alignment here is just bad. The guiding principle should be: Does it aid readability? For me, the answer is a resounding no.

Comment: @canon: Yeah even I'm 50/50 on this one, but slightly misaligned `=` — and these two are close enough — cause me more OCD grief than the alternative!

Comment: Here, they don't even look aligned to me. I can tell they are by dragging a vertical line (edge of a window) over the post, but there's some optical illusion here for me that makes the bottom `=` appear slightly to the right of the top one.

Comment: That's just plain awful.  I find the suggested formatting to be *worse* than the unformatted version and would roll this monstrosity back in a heartbeat.

Comment: @cimmanon Don't just complain, help improve! How would you write it?

Comment: I would have left it exactly as it was written.  To alter anything other than the use of markdown or to make the indentation consistent is frivolous.

Comment: @cimmanon Well, that's my point, I guess: the original version had readability problems, and so did the applied edit. Making answers more readable is generally accepted here, I thought the only discussion was on what is and what isn't more readable.

Comment: Alignment of unrelated things is a travesty. The aim of formatting is *readability* not *beauty*. Columns of assignment may look pretty, but they make *understanding* the code harder as they disjoin two related things to make unrelated things align. I don't think I know of a language that has a style guide that doesn't say never to align such things.

Comment: @Lattyware That's a fair point, it's not what I originally had in my answer here, and it detracts from the point I was trying to make. I'll edit that out.

Comment: @hvd - on my pc, the original format doesn't result in horizontal scroll bar. Even if I make the browser window narrow. Is this dependent on the screen size of the device you are reading on?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I'm reading it on a desktop PC, with a maximised Firefox window on a 1920x1080 screen, and resizing the browser window doesn't make any difference. I see the same result in Chromium.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow has two slightly contradicting goals and mechanisms:

- to provide a *collaboratively* curated repository of useful content that will make the world a better place,
- to get users to participate by providing content and rewarding *individualistic* behaviour.

The author's username is the one really attached to an answer. This Stack Overflow user is what is affected by the reputation points linked to that answer. Reputation points aside, it can also have an element of more general pride.

One could say people should be too proud and possessive, but I think this individual pride generally has positive side-effects, in that people care about what they write, which tends to improve the content quality in general.

Stack Overflow isn't Wikipedia: the author's name has always been clearly visible and the nature of the game has always encouraged a behaviour that makes everyone be more concious about how their own content.

There is a difference with editors and authors, and the way they are represented on Stack Overflow. The problem is that when reading an answer, at first glance, one could attribute the whole content (including content with which the original author may disagree) to that author. (Of course, this can be investigated with the revision history, but this can be cumbersome, and many occasional visitors wouldn't know about that anyway.)

This is why minor edits are acceptable, but edits that can change the meaning of an answer are not.

In this particular case, formatting is generally considered acceptable (since it's a minor edit). Cases where an author doesn't accept the formatting edits are rare. Perhaps the author shared the point of view expressed in @hvd's answer (that it may be better to read everything without having to scroll). This seems to be a relatively new user who might not have been fully familiar with how to format code here.

In general, don't get into an edit war with the initial author. If they don't consider the edit you've made as improvements, so be it. Let the voters decide whether they like their answer or not as they've written it: this might lead to more downvotes or fewer upvotes without your improvements.

Answer (score -16):

I've had people edit my posts to "fix" the grammar.  I'm a native English speaker who knows my grammar.  I don't need or want the "fix".

Comment: Being a native English speaker in no way stops you from making grammatical mistakes. The aim of SO is to produce an archive of information, and the only bar to editing is if the edit improves the content. It may well be that perfectly correct grammar is less clear or understandable. I take from the quotes around *fix* in your answer, that the change actually took correct English and mangled it, which is indeed wrong and should be rolled back, but, as mentioned before, humans are falliable. That's no reason to dislike edits in general.

Comment: If you're referring to [this post history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21482586/revisions), then yes, that edit was incorrect and shouldn't have been made. I would have even rolled it back completely instead of merely reverting the part that's *clearly* wrong. I do agree with Lattyware though: if you had typed "it's" yourself, which could have happened as a typo, then there would be nothing wrong with someone else correcting that to "its".

Comment: There are many native speakers who don't seem to know the difference between "your" and "you're", "it's" and "its" or even "affect" and "effect". Some also quite frequently try to use "below" as an adjective, when it is not (e.g. "*the below code*"). Even for those who know the difference, some still make typos once in a while.

Comment: Its realy not unlikly for an native english speaker to make a Mistake or too, and the affect is reduced when someone makes a edit with the Aim of effecting it positivelly.

Comment: @Lattyware "*It's realy [...]*", surely, you meant "*Its realy [...]*" ;-)

Comment: @Bruno Phew, fixed - thanks for the heads up - that would have been embarrassing.

Comment: @Bruno Actually, "below" appears as an adjective in some dictionaries. An example is [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/below).

Comment: So with you on this. I have had non-native English speaking members edit my original posts, and I have no idea what they were thinking. Result? Rollback, and a warning to leave my post alone. The only reason I can think of for editing an otherwise concise, perfectly readable post is for attention. Maybe that person thinks himself an unsung genius? Having written professionally for newspapers, blogs, and a master's thesis, sometimes with teams of editors changing my work in undesirable ways, the last person I want touching my work is a pretend editor with substandard language skills.

Comment: You could simply roll back, without the "warning to leave your post alone". Tone down the ego a notch. Professional writers almost always have editors look over their work. When they don't, you can tell.