# Are Edit: and Update: notes in posts encouraged?

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently had a comments discussion in which I disagreed with someone as to whether "Edit:" or "Update:" notes are a good thing in post amendments. My interlocutor said that there used to be a question about this on MSO, but that it had been deleted. Either way, it would be good to find out what the community prefers, so we know how to edit in future.

My opinion is that "Edit:" notes are not ideal — we are aiming (somewhat) towards Wikipedia as a writing model, rather than a forum or a chatroom. It is true that the 'Edit' note might be useful for people who have already read a post and would find it useful to have their attention drawn towards an update. However, a *much* larger number of people will read it in the future, and their purposes will be best served with a question or answer that has all of its updates unobtrusively merged into it.

Thus, when editing some questions/answers, I will remove them and reword if I can. Of course, some Edit: notes are too hard to meld into the body of the post; I'll leave these alone if it would turn into a rewrite.

It was suggested to me that the phrase "Editor's note" is useful to show that a post has been edited by a third party, so that the OP is not blamed for someone else's changes. I'm not in favour of that either for the above reasons, and also:

- the OP can roll back if they believe the edit is poor
- readers can check the edit history if they wish to find out who was responsible for which paragraph

What does the community think?

Comment: Gah! a dup, even after persistent searching! Thanks, and apologies.

Comment: It's a different discussion, but I'm not sure we're really aiming somewhat towards a Wikipedia model. As I was saying in [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270583/372643), and I think that some loose notion of "ownwership" of answers is actually at the core of how SE is designed, and is overall quite beneficial. The spirit of the site according to the FAQ (and general behaviour) has always been that edits should be minors, and the main mechanism has always been to encourage distinct answers.