# Stack Snippet retcon

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

Is it considered a valid edit to replace links to JSFiddle or similar sites with new Stack Snippets?

If the answer is "sometimes," what makes it valid or not?

Comment: Related: [Should we edit our old posts to include Stack Snippets?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271506/1048572)

Comment: Excellent question. I think BoltClock [has it exactly right](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271500/stack-snippet-retcon#comment94828_271502) on hichris123's answer (which is also good).

Answer (score 22):

I really think it's fine to create one whenever editing. But let's start with two scenarios:

1. **The OP included a link to their JSFiddle, but no code**. This should definitely be edited to include the code. Now, are you feeling amazing today, and want to create a Stack Snippet? Go right ahead! You're already editing the question to bring the code in: why not?
2. **The OP included a link to their JSFiddle, and their code in the question/answer**. This one is a bit grayer to me. But in all honesty, no one's going to get mad at you for adding extra features to their question. I really don't think there's a problem with creating a Stack Snippet here, but use your best judgement on removing the link to JSFiddle. Some people are particular about their questions/answers... and for some situations JSFiddle might be better for some random reason.

Bottom line: edit it in whenever you're feeling like it. If you feel like taking the effort to edit it in, that's great! If you don't want to, well, that's your choice. But it will make it easier for future readers and/or answerers (if it's a question) to understand/answer.

Be sure that you have a purpose for doing so, though: don't just go back to old posts and edit them into snippets for no reason. Edit them in as you come across them.

Comment: I'd also add to not go back and mass-edit old JSFiddle posts to change them to Stack Snippets: edit them following this *as you come across them*.

Comment: @AstroCB yeah, feel free to edit that in.

Comment: "But in all honesty, no one's going to get mad at you for adding extra features to their question." [lol no.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270503/user-didnt-like-my-edit-and-rolled-back-should-i-edit-again/270504#270504)

Comment: Also, if you don't have full editing privileges, I would add that, as always, your time is better spent on posts that *need* editing. Don't bother with #2 - as long as the code is in the question, it's fine. If it ain't broke, don't fix it, etc.

Comment: @BoltClock re 1: sure, there's some people out there... and you just have to respect that. re 2: yep. I was going to put that in, but... of course, I forgot. ;p Also for people with full editing privs, if you're fixing other stuff, go ahead, otherwise, why waste your time.