# Should we edit our old posts to include Stack Snippets?

Tags: discussion, edits, stack-snippets

Obviously only our posts which include HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript, and that would perhaps benefit by having this feature in the post itself.

What does Stack Exchange Inc. think?

What do the moderators think?

What do you think?

I'm unsure currently, since it would take quite a while to go back through each one of my posts to edit these in. Maybe only do the posts that are in the top 5 percentile of your posts in terms of score? Or maybe edit the ones where the question has over *N* amount of views?

Comment: @DavidPostill that post seems to be more about editing other people's posts. I'm looking to hear about what people think about editing their own posts. If they are planning on doing them all, none, or some of them.. etc

Comment: @lostsock: there is little point in such a discussion; that's little more than a poll.

Comment: Could SO do it maybe automatically for all suitable code snippets?

Comment: @Trilarion why? What benefit would there be for converting old questions no one is going to be looking at with a view to answering.

Comment: And no, there would be no point in doing it automatically, as most snippets would break.

Comment: @ChrisF If the assumption is right that no one is looking at old questions then why keeping them at all? If the snippets wouldn't break it would make sense to bring everything to the newest state of technology in my opinion. But I didn't think it through - of course they will break. So forget this idea.

Comment: @Trilarion I didn't say no one was looking at all, just that they weren't looking to answer. People have the same problem, search, find the question and it's answer and then use the code in the answer. There's no real need to convert the code to a runnable snippet in this scenario.

Comment: @ChrisF Okay, you convinced me.

Comment: Personally, I'd say as a generic rule, convert any questions (where appropriate) that don't currently have an answer. For questions that do have an answer, whatever the question is, it clearly did enough and explained the problem well enough to get a suitable answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can only edit 10 of your posts in a day.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't make a special effort to edit your old posts. If you need to edit it anyway and a snippet would be appropriate, then **that's** the time to do the conversion.

Flooding the home page with lots of edits isn't appreciated, not even on Stack Overflow where the lifetime of a question on the home page is short.

Comment: Or *especially* not on Stack Overflow where the lifetime of a question on the home page is short; flooding it with edited posts flushes out regular content even faster before anyone could even see it.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to explicitly mark an edit as _non-bumping_. I would love to replace my jsfiddles with stacksnippets.

Comment: Ah, but if your old post is well-frequented, polishing it to a bright shine is a good idea. So, use the opportunity.

Comment: It might be a good idea in old, canonical (often-linked, often-viewed) questions though, where updates to old answers are good practise anyway.

Comment: @canon: [Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122567/allow-non-bumping-minor-edits-but-review-them-on-review) on meta.sx. I think it's not quite as simple as letting people mark edits as non-bumping (although maybe it is for high-rep users…), but I also think it's worth working something out…

Comment: So, the main thing is to avoid *systematically* visiting a bunch of your old posts with intent to convert them?