# I need more edits, so how do I contact a moderator?

Tags: support, feature-request

I'm trying to convert all my answers that have a JSFiddle/Plunkr/JSBin/etc.-answers, into [the awesome new format](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1). However the website notified me that I'm only allowed 5 edits of my own posts a day, and is saying i need to contact a moderator.

[image]

This should probably include a link on how to contact one, I assume through Meta or through a chatroom? "need more edits" isn't an option in the support contact form so I thought i'd hit two birds with one stone and put a question on meta.

Comment: Also i have 7 answers still to edit, so give me more than 5, thanks!

Comment: Nothing anyone can do.  Wait until tomorrow.

Comment: If you have to (not in this case): Contact a mod by flagging one of your questions, and fill in the 'other' reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Normally you contact a moderator by raising a flag on a post and selecting the "other" option.

However, in this case if you did your flag would be declined as what you are doing is not welcome behaviour.

The limit it set up for various reasons:

- to stop people vandalising their posts if they try to "rage quit" the site. The "contact us" option is to get them to request account deletion in the proper way.
- someone realises that they've left sensitive information in all their posts. In this case we can edit and get the team to remove the revisions from the history.

The correct action for you is to wait until tomorrow to edit the rest of your posts. However, I refer you to my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271506/should-we-edit-our-old-posts-to-include-stack-snippets/271507#271507):

> Don't make a special effort to edit your old posts. If you need to edit it anyway and a snippet would be appropriate, then that's the time to do the conversion.
>
> Flooding the home page with lots of edits isn't appreciated, not even on Stack Overflow where the lifetime of a question on the home page is short.

Comment: If I wanted to change your "*...not even on Stack Overflow...*" to "*...especially on Stack Overflow...*", I'd probably have to do it on the source post, as well! ;) Though, now that I think of it; the appearance on the front page of these edits would be worse on low-traffic sites.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - such is life :)

Comment: First-world problems, and all!

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't go about converting all your older posts to the "snippet" format:
[Should we edit our old posts to include Stack Snippets?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271506/should-we-edit-our-old-posts-to-include-stack-snippets)

As answered on that question:

> Flooding the home page with lots of edits isn't appreciated, not even on Stack Overflow where the lifetime of a question on the home page is short.

I'm pretty sure no-one's going to get more edits just because of this new feature.

Comment: So, is it plagiarism for ChrisF to link to the same post of his in his answer here that you did? ;)

Comment: I am flagging it for plagiarism @AndrewBarber ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Absolutely :P If you cite something that someone cited that you said, you should credit the person that originally stole... err, cited your own words :P

Comment: @Cerbrus May I quote you on that?