# Suggested Edit Replacing JSFiddle with Stack Snippet, what to do?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I'm reviewing a suggested edit that wraps the code in a stack snippet and removes the JSFiddle link:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5797556

I have skipped the review since I'm not sure whether to approve or reject.

What should be done in case I found something similar?

Comment: Looks like the Stack Snippets UI isn't rendered in the output diff. That could be a problem.

Comment: Since there is really no point to having a snippet containing a question's broken code example, I reverted the edit.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As these are clearly not being done by the OP I would reject them.

There is absolutely no point in mass editing posts to convert code to Stack Snippets as I've said both [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271507/59303), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271536/59303) and on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239541/yay-we-have-runnable-code-snippets-do-i-go-and-edit-all-my-questions-causing/239542#239542).

If you find you have to edit **one of your own posts** for any reason then *that's* the time to update any code to be a snippet.

Comment: Perhaps the edit interface should temporarily display a warning with this info?

Comment: @ChrisF, I have rejected two suggested edit that converted to stack snippet, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5807887) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5807960), but the majority approved the review, Was I wrong? Or should I keep rejecting those?

Comment: @YuliamChandra - the fact that others don't do the right thing shouldn't stop you. Carry on rejecting, other's might eventually get the message.

Comment: If somebody happens to be reading a new post that's already on the front page, and it's clear that a stack snippet would make the question or answer obvious and easy to demonstrate, why _not_ edit it if it only takes a moment? It does no harm.

Comment: @ChrisF People don't get the message unless you mass-ban them.

Comment: @nhinkle that's not what I'm concerned about. If you're doing that sort of thing, then you're not doing mass edits.

Comment: `the fact that others don't do the right thing shouldn't stop you. Carry on rejecting, other's might eventually get the message.` And that, kids, is why StackOverflow's review process is flawed.

Comment: Should we be encouraging people to treat posts originally authored by someone else different than posts originally authored by themselves? I would think that the right course of action is the right course of action regardless of original authorship.

Comment: @corsika the issue is that **old** posts are being mass edited. If it was a new one, I'd be less concerned.

Comment: @ChrisF: So [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5821390) I just came across is OK?

Comment: @Bergi - I would have said it was pointless. I ran the snippet and, as it counted down from 1 minute, I assumed it was working. If it was meant to show that the code was broken it didn't do that at all.

Comment: @ChrisF, should we rollback approved suggested edits that simply add in a stack snippet, especially if the snippet has no use. For instance, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5910888) the snippet does nothing, doesn't log anything to the console, has nothing for html, and does not demonstrate broken code

Comment: @PatrickEvans - treat it like any other edit. If it's useless or makes the post worse roll it back.

Comment: It'd be nice if we could flag our own edits to our posts as low-impact or something so as not to affect question sorting.