# Answering a code question: JSFiddle link or SO Snippet?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets, jsfiddle

I've seen a large number of JSFiddle links with the code also included in the answer (example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31946170/989920).

This to me is good practice, but is it best practice for SO answers?

Should we be using the snippet feature instead?

---

I am asking this as I was challenged when I edited a good answer to include a SO snippet and not a JSFiddle link. The quoted comment is below.

> I'm not clear if it is required to use the snippet feature rather than an external service - especially if I believe the external service is more appropriate or clearer. If you can provide guidance on this I'll accept your edit - otherwise i'll reject it..

Comment: I think it's better to use an SO snippet if the Q&A is about web technologies. Edited: Ah, I missed that this is about editing someone else's post. I'm not sure how important it is that the *runnable* version of the code is on SO as long as the code is there.

Comment: To those downvoting, please tell me why. I can edit the question or delete it. Don't anonymously downvote.

Comment: I haven't voted but on Meta a down vote is likely to mean disagreement.

Comment: How can one disagree with a question? I'm just asking what's preferred, if any.

Comment: Preferred by whom? I think it's pretty obvious that stack snippets should be used on stackoverflow when asking/answering questions. stack snippets are of course useless however in comments.

Comment: I thought so too, but I've had a number of people reject my requests for snippets in favour of JSFiddle links.

Comment: As far as editing someone else's post to use an SO snippet, [a mod has said not to to that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271589/suggested-edit-replacing-jsfiddle-with-stack-snippet-what-to-do).

Comment: Thanks @BSMP. I'll make sure to encourage snippets rather than edit posts to include them.

Comment: @apaul34208 That's what I was looking for, I did a number of searches and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @evolutionxbox we both posted on same issue at same time. I upvoted yours as I believe we both had a genuine question

Comment: @DavidAnderton yours actually has an answer. It also is more complete.

Comment: @BSMP, generally users < 2k should shy away from doing any edits which introduce code into the post *because* it is likely that they will be rejected. Users > 2k should and probably will edit the code into the post because that is the right thing to do and users generally don't listen. **Edit:** as long as it is not mass-editing.

Comment: In the post in the question, the code was already in the question itself, it just wasn't in a snippet.

Comment: @BSMP it was because I edited it in.

Comment: Right. I was talking about before you edited it.

Comment: @BSMP what do you mean by mass editing?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Is when someone uses a search to find posts with a common problem, then only fixes that one thing in every post in the results.