# Would I be prohibited by Stack Overflow rules/regulations from using a tool to help me edit questions?

Tags: discussion

I just thought of a trivial but fun project I'd like to attempt, but I wouldn't want to break the rules.

My idea was to program a crawler that would find JS fiddle links in Stack Overflow questions and replace them (via an edit) with their code contents via the new SE Code Snippet tool.

I'm not sure that I'm allowed to use a program to assist in my use of Stack Overflow though.

For *licensing* concerns, I created [a separate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275454/can-i-without-getting-into-licensing-trouble-convert-code-from-jsfiddles-to-se).

---

**For the sake of the question, let's say it's a tool that fixes poor grammar, or any tool in general.** Don't focus on the specifics of the tool, I won't be doing that one after getting feedback on that kind of editing being discouraged.

Imagine, for example as a comment below mentions:

> a bot that alerts you of questions with errors and then you fixing the
>   errors and other issues with the post yourself.

Comment: See - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271507/

Comment: See also - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242353/is-it-recommended-to-convert-code-in-existing-posts-to-stack-snippets/242354#242354

Comment: Forget about the program, why is this even necessary?  Spend your time making useful edits?

Comment: @psubsee2003 because the program is fun to attempt :)

Comment: I think people here are confused between a bad question (deserving a downvote) and "The answer is no.", because I think the -3 on this question should have been three answers / comments saying  "no this isn't a good idea" not down-votes saying "No this isnt a good question"

Comment: Make it also find code snippets that are *not* Javascript and I'll thank you for it.

Comment: From what I'm gathering, such programs are not recommended as they can't make other needed edits to the post.  But I (note: I am not a moderator and this is NOT an official opinion) see no harm in making a bot that **alerts you of questions with errors** and then you fixing the errors and other issues with the post yourself.

Comment: @Pokechu22 see that's a good idea.

Comment: Also note that on Meta, downvotes on questions are used to indicate disagreement unlike on the main site where they indicate question quality, as votes on Meta don't actually affect reputation.

Comment: I see. Didn't realize that.

Comment: Yeah from what I've seen that's supposed to just be for feature requests, but people don't discriminate much

Comment: I'm not sure if this is completely related to what you're asking here, but I've created a tool that fixes a lot of common errors in posts here and I've been using it for a month or two now. I'm quite pleased with it, but I don't trust it enough to run automated editing tasks without my approval, so I only use it manually. Feel free to [take a look at it on GitHub](https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit) and contribute if you're into that sort of thing, because we could use some help with the open issues.

Comment: @AstroCB I'll check it out. I've been wanted to work on a GitHub project just for experience with the system anyway.

Comment: @AstroCB Stack Exchange loads JQuery by default - would you be adverse to my pull request introducing Jquery / simplifying the script in JQuery form?

Comment: Automatic spell 'fix' - no way - see the 'clbuttic'. 
It's a programming way, how a non-human can distinct between human language and variable names etc.? Even people have problems with it ('translating' variable names etc.)

Comment: I like the question, but I disagree with the idea.

Answer (score 2):

As part of the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) some of its members either created or enhanced existing tooling to make moderation easier.

The ones [used or supported](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation#any-resources-to-help) by the room regulars are:

- [Shortcut keys](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/CloseVoteShortcuts.user.js) - A script that allows a user to use the number keys to click review buttons, speeding up review time.
- [Pre-baked Comments](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments) to be used with [Auto review Comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)
- [Bot Commands Auto-complete](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/BotCommands.user.js) - Auto completes commands for the chat bot.
- [Stack Exchange Editor Toolkit](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit) - Fixes most common grammatical and usage errors with a click
- [Other user scripts](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts)

What you describe in your question is in some form part of the Stack Exchange Editor Toolkit and I use it when I'm burninating tags so I can fix posts quickly with the most common errors. This still needs a human though to check if it didn't fail or replaced or left wrong stuff (it comes with a handy diff to show that).

I don't think an automated and unsupervised tool to replace JSFiddles with Stack Snippets would be easy to build or wise to do. Not only is the feature richness of jsFiddle better then Stack Snippets, you also would need to test every snippet to see if it still works.

Editing is a complex task that is best done by humans with the support of tooling. Not solely by tooling with bugs created by humans.