# Edit posts to include external fiddles in post

Tags: discussion, edits, stack-snippets

Should new posts that include external fiddles (JSFiddle, Codepen, ...) be edited to include SO code snippets?

Especially when a post has no code included at all.

In contrast to [Should we edit our old posts to include Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271506/should-we-edit-our-old-posts-to-include-stack-snippets) I'm not talking about old question I asked myself. But rather when looking at and editing new posts by other users.

Comment: Related question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271506/should-we-edit-our-old-posts-to-include-stack-snippets?rq=1

Comment: It's not an *exact* duplicate: this is asking about editing new questions while the dupe link is talking about old questions. For **new** questions that don't have the code in the question itself, it is appropriate to edit it in. If the question has issues that need fixing, it's OK to convert existing plain code into a snippet while you're editing it anyway. But if the question includes the code and has no other problems, just leave it. There's a good chance of that being seen as not enough of an improvement on its own.

Comment: If it's a debugging question that's missing the code, you can also just flag it.