# People turning regular code blocks in others' question into snippets

Tags: discussion, edits, stack-snippets

I came across the following edit: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25922292/2

The editor made the code block a stack snippet, but in this case, the code is writing to the console, which doesn't give any visual feedback inside the snippet.

The editor did add a `document.write`, but the OP took it out since it ws not part of his code.

Is it okay that people edit other's posts to pointlessly add a snippet?

Comment: You answered it already by yourself. If it is pointless, then it is not ok ;-)

Comment: See also - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271589/suggested-edit-replacing-jsfiddle-with-stack-snippet-what-to-do

Comment: I haven't read much about Code Snippet decisions, but I find it way easier to press F12 and click a button than F12, Copy, Paste, Enter.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No.

If you see these edits in the queue, reject them; in this case, the snippet was added simply for the purpose of adding the snippet, which is unacceptable.

The OP reviewed this as Edit, which is likely the only reason it was approved, since it was otherwise useless.

[It's okay to add snippets to questions as you come across them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271502/3366929) **if they need them**, but, as usual, make sure you address all issues with the post.

Comment: "...which is likely the only reason it was approved". I wish I was still that naive myself. We have a large number of edit reviewers who approve literally anything. And their numbers are increasing... I can't even bother flagging them any longer.

Comment: @Lundin: And now it seems to be official policy to approve everything which might be an enhancement.

Comment: @Deduplicator Which is kind of a design error. There are many edits that are just "meh", they are neither improvements nor outright vandalism.

Comment: @Lundin At that point it's a judgement call, if you feel like approving it, you do, if not reject it. I'm not fond about our new "let's approve any small improvement despite leaving obvious other things that need improvement" for the sake of removing "Too minor".