# When should I elaborate answers to make them better?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

For example, we have 2 situations:

1. Accepted answer.
2. Not accepted answer yet (but a very good answer).

I know something that is related to the question and is good elaboration for the answer.

In what cases can I edit the question and elaborate it and when I should not do that?

P.S. I've recently edited an answer on Stack Overflow of a 15k-rating user. I was really afraid of doing this because I was surprised he did not write in his answer what I want to elaborate. After my edit he turned the answer back to his own edit with an explanation:

> @VictorPolevoy That's a good suggestion, but you should add it in an
>   answer of your own: I'm just directly answering the question.

I thought it is always good to elaborate good answers to make them better. In my own experience, when I search something on Stack Overflow I want to see all-in-one answers. That makes me not waste much time in getting a full answer on the question, however I understand that it is good to read all of the answers anyway. Also, good, full answers can be a wiki-like answer, in my own opinion.

About duplicates:
@gnat this is not a duplicate. User in [this "duplicate" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270503) asked about simple code formatting while I am asking about a good contribution and not just simple edit of the text. It is not enough big to make it be a separate answer and it is not so few to say it can be a comment to the answer.

I think, this is a good question on here because a lot of people may be confused about this.

Comment: If you want to add something substantially new then it's often best to add your own answer. It's fine to have information spread across multiple answers, it's relatively normal.

Comment: For clarity, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31473953/496161) is the answer in question.

Comment: _It is not enough big to make it be a separate answer_ - If you need info from the existing answer for your own to make sense, you can credit the other user for the content. You can even point out that they told you to make it a separate answer if you're worried about accusations of plagiarism.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're adding something really substantial, consider adding an answer of your own.

SO is a collaborative effort to collect knowledge - but it's still not entirely a wiki.

Answers written by individually identified authors are very much at the core of the model.

By substantially editing someone else's answer you are putting words in their mouth that simply aren't theirs - even though the content may be of good quality.

Introducing new code into someone's answer is especially problematic, as the original author can not know what possible problems or issues the code has, while  in the eye of the public, they're going to be the ones responsible for it.